# How to push/load jmeter results to S3 (Amazon services) bucket after running Docker Jmeter master container/bin path (non gui mode)

Tags: jmeter

Docker Jmeter master dockfile should have a script to load/push the results.csv/jtl/xml files to S3 bucket. Please help to achieve the same, what parameters needs to be added to docker jmeter master container/dockfile.

How to push/load jmeter results to S3 (Amazon services) bucker after running Docker Jmeter master container/bin path (non gui mode)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own docker image which incorporates this behavior by extending the existing docker image. To do this, you must create your own Dockerfile like this:

```shell
FROM jmeter-image

# Install aws-cli
# configure aws-cli with your own access / secret key.
```

Here is a example Dockerfile to create a JMeter image:
https://github.com/hauptmedia/docker-jmeter/blob/master/Dockerfile

Also, I would suggest to make tinier docker images using alpine-java as a base image like explained here:
https://octoperf.com/blog/2016/02/11/small-java-docker-images/